# SSRS - How can I create a custom aggregate function?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a report that has an unusual BoxPlot chart.  I need to calculate the values for "Low Box" and "High Box" using all of the data for the certain column.  The methodology for calculating these values is not that complicated, but I can not disclose it.

Basically I want to create a custom aggregate function.  I understand how to create a VB function, but how do I make it take in a series of data instead of a single value.  I know there is a Max function already, but for the sake of example how would one implement a Max function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"can not disclose it." implies high value, which implies that you are using a recent version of SSRS, so [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/07/20/using-group-variables-in-reporting-services-2008-for-custom-aggregation.aspx) should be of value for you. (The blog article also includes how you might implement this in 2005, but doesn't focus on it.)

Essentially create a custom function that gets called for every row of the data, taking in values from that row. That method or another related method can return your aggregate. 2008 includes Group Variables should help with a convenient place to store that.

Another approach, but much harder I think, would be to implement a custom data provider wrapping your query.

Comment: I marked your question as correct, but I think I will add another database table and use that for this report.  This table would contain aggregated data from other tables, and SSRS would just read it into my chart.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie F . The group variables did the worked for me.